# Merge/append two csv files by columns with no common index

Tags: python, pandas, csv, merge

I have two csv files

csv1 - I issue a cmd command and write that in to file1.

```
timestamp     ref_id    rx        ry     tag      repeat    backoff
1561333986465   44   47.8312    11.0052  c_tag      0        0 
1561334690976   44   47.8312    11.0052  c_tag      1       1500
1561334703668   44   47.8312    11.0052  c_tag      2       1500
```

csv2 - The results of that particular command gets posted to  file2.

```
tStart         source   trackingID  anchs   x        y    z
1561333987329   toa        0           8    96      2.5   4
1561334691738   toa        0           8    95.2    2.2   4
1561334693818   toa        0           8    98.5    3.7   4
1561334704328   toa        0           8    96.6    2.9   4
1561334706428   toa        0           8    95.8    2.6   4
1561334708517   toa        0           8    97.3    4.3   4
```

If the repeat is set to 0 the command runs once and the result is also posted once. if repeat = 1 the command runs twice and the results are posted twice. So, if repeat is set to n the command runs n+1 times and result gets posted n+1 times to csv2. I need to merge these two files in a way such that first 7 columns post the command and next 7 the results.

```
import csv

in_1_name = "/home/input.csv"
in_2_name = "/home/excel/output.csv"
out_name = "/home/merge/merged.csv"

with open(in_1_name) as in_1, open(in_2_name) as in_2, open(out_name, 'w') as out:
    reader1 = csv.reader(in_1, delimiter=";")
    reader2 = csv.reader(in_2, delimiter=";")
    writer = csv.writer(out, delimiter=";")
    for row1, row2 in zip(reader1, reader2):
        if row1[0] and row2[0]:
            writer.writerow([row1[0], row2[0]])
```

The code above just merges the columns from csv1 to csv2, since there is nothing common between two csv's I am not able to find a way to get the expected results. Any help is appreciated.

```
expected result :

timestamp   ref_id  rx  ry  tag repeat  backoff tStart  source  trackingID  anchs   x   y   z
1561333986465   44  47.8312 11.0052 c_tag   0   0   1561333987329   toa 0   8   96  2.5 4
1561334690976   44  47.8312 11.0052 c_tag   1   1500    1561334691738   toa 0   8   95.2    2.2 4
X   X   X   X   X   X       1561334693818   toa 0   8   98.5    3.7 4
1561334703668   44  47.8312 11.0052 c_tag   2   1500    1561334704328   toa 0   8   96.6    2.9 4
X   X   X   X   X   X   X   1561334706428   toa 0   8   95.8    2.6 4
X   X   X   X   X   X   X   1561334708517   toa 0   8   97.3    4.3 4
```

Comment: you will need pandas concat: `pd.concat`. create two dataframes, `reader1df` and `reader2df`, then do  `pd.concat([reader1df, reader1df], ignore_index=True)`

Comment: But there is nothing common between two csv's, how do I map my command to the results it created, one row in csv1 might generate n rows in csv2, should I call pd.concat() every time I issue a command ?
 thanks@MEdwin